# Laravel Mysql setup on ubuntu giving error [1698] on running php aritsan migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu, migrate

I installed laravel and setup username and database in mysql.

Then I entered the credentials in database.php file in Laravel project.

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'msn_test1'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'msn_user' ),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'Passw0rd!'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

But when I run:

```
 php artisan migrate
```

I get this error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

I am new to Laravel. Could someone help me with the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter is the fallback value `env('the_env_property_name', 'fallback_variable')`, it will fallback if it is not present in the `.env` file.

You should put these variables in the .env file, create your `.env` file by copying the `.env.example` to `.env`. Set the variables as done below, they are probably already there.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_USERNAME=msn_user
DB_PASSWORD=Passw0rd!
```

Answer (score 0):

The .env file is hidden in the project home folder. I found while creating a new one.